# How to Convert This Sql Query TO Django Query

Tags: django

I want Get UID Based on Email Filtering
Like "(select Uid From User_master where email = 'xyz.gmail.com')"
How to Convert This Sql Query TO Django Query

Comment: Please share the corresponding model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will retrieve all User_master objects with the specified email and only retrieve the Uid

```
from .models import User_master

user_uid = User_master.objects.filter(email='xyz.gmail.com').values_list('Uid', flat=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a model that contains the 'email', 'user_master', 'id', then beneath the model (but within its tab) you can try something like the following (the @property decorator enables one to use the function as though its a part of the model)

```
@property
def myEmailerId(self):
    queryset = self.email.all().values_list('user_master__id', flat=True)
    return queryset
```